# how to change the display language in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded a copy at http://mergedoc.sourceforge.jp/ eclipse 3.7, but this IDE is Japanese, I want to change it into English, anyone can help me?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why didn't you download an English copy instead?

Answer (score 27):

add the  `-Duser.language=en` jvm argument  after the `-vmargs` parameter in the eclipse.ini file

Comment: I did as above but it has no effect at all

Comment: are you sure you put it after the -vmargs line in the eclipse.ini file  ? Can you post your eclipse.ini file ?

Comment: this is content eclipse.ini
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-javaagent:dropins/MergeDoc/eclipse/plugins/jp.sourceforge.mergedoc.pleiades/pleiades.jar

Comment: You forgot to mention that it needs to be added after the -vmargs parameter.

Answer (score 17):

This question is quite old but I just want to share what worked for me.

I assume you are using Pleiades based on your eclipse.ini file.

I found this:

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/shiraji/20130427/1367054426

It basically says:

1. Comment out the following line from eclipse.ini:

   ```
   #-javaagent:dropins/MergeDoc/eclipse/plugins/jp.sourceforge.mergedoc.pleiades/pleiades.jar
   ```
2. Delete the following:

   ```
   plugins/jp.sourceforge.mergedoc.jstyle_4.2.2.1    
   configuration/jp.sourceforge.mergedoc
   ```

   (In my case, the second folder is `jp.sourceforge.mergedoc.pleiades`).
3. Restart Eclipse

You should now see the regular Eclipse splash screen and the menus now set to English.

Answer (score 8):

You can put the following parameter in your eclipse.ini file, **before** the -vmargs params :

```
-nl
en
```

Comment: If your ini file has already an entry like this, then changing the language in the 2nd line helps.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it worked only when I changed it like this:

`-vmargs -nl en`

Answer (score 0):

Sometime -nl en might not work so you can try -nl en_US